# Continuous, null-average function

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to prove that the set

$$
Z=\left\{u\in C^0([0,1]): \int_0^1u(x)\mathrm{d}x=0\right\}
$$

is *not* closed. I tried to work out a counterexample... but it seems that I proved the opposite thing: if I take a sequence $\left\{u_n\right\}\in Z$ and I suppose that $u_n\rightarrow u$, as the convergence is uniform, I can state that $\int_0^1u_n(x)\mathrm{d}x\rightarrow \int_0^1u(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and so $u\in Z$ and so $Z$ would be closed. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Closed in which topology? If $u \mapsto \int_0^1 u(x)\,dx$ is continuous, then $Z$ _is_ closed.

Comment: My apologies that I am not an expert on functional analysis. what you said is correct, uniform convergence implies convergence of the integral. To define an open or closed set we need a topology. what is the topology here? If the topology is the topology generated by the $L^\infty$ norm, then this set is closed.

Comment: The topology is the standard one induced by $\sup$-norm

Comment: So $Z$ is closed.

Comment: indeed ^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: The astonishing fact is that on the same book, the exercise after the one above, seems to me even more wrong:

Prove that the set
$$
\left\{u\in C^0([0,1]):u(0)=1\right\}
$$

is *closed*, convex, and *dense*. How it is possible to be closed and dense? Shouldn't be $C([0,1])$ in this case?

Comment: Closed and dense is possible in exactly one way: being the entire space. What book is that?

Comment: The book is by Giaquinta and Modica. It is in italian, the third volume. I actually don't know if there is an english version of that volume.

Comment: Never heard of the authors. But your examples strongly hint that at least the exercises are not to be recommended.

Comment: How is it possible? A sequence of continous function always converges (uniformly) to a continous function!

Comment: f*c* this book!